# How can I trade BTC for other crypto currencies?

Tags: altcoin-trade

How do I withdraw from BTC and credit to LTC or withdraw from LTC and credit to BTC or any cryptocurrencies?

Answer (score 1):

Use an exchange such as [Bittrex](https://bittrex.com/), [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/), [ShapeShift](https://shapeshift.io/), etc.
There you can create an account, deposit your BTC to your account, trade one cryptocurrency for another, and withdraw your new coins to an external wallet.

Comment: but i want to make own platform is it possible?